# Javascript Calendar

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop, calendar

I am looking for a Javascript calendar with support for drag-and-drop, extensive events model (drag, drop, deletion/adding of items).

Also has to be capable of displaying a schedule for multiple persons. That'd be something similar to "Multiple Resources" view of http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

Free/paid does not matter. Has to work across major browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: and why you are searching for another one while you know dhtmlxScheduler? what you didn't like about dhtmlxScheduler ?

Comment: To my understanding, dhtmlxScheduler does not have support for "finished dragging" event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, writing my own calendar, based on jQuery's draggable/droppable UI component is not that hard, and is way more flexible and extensible. There are some WTFs along the way, mostly to do with weird behaviour of dragging/dropping in IE(7/8) and some weirdness around snap to grid behaviour in jQuery UI's draggable, but I think it would take longer if I just took an existing control and tried to customise it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether it can do multiple schedules out of the box, but check out the JQuery based [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Comment: I use jQuery Fullcalendar in my web app. It rocks. Well documented with all the hooks you need to do virtually anything. I manage 13 different employee schedules viewable individually or in groups.

Comment: They still don't support event management - dragging to create, click to edit, for example. So I guess you'd have to do it yourself. I'm actually now searching for such a solution or alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

For scheduling multiple resources I'd recommend the Ext Scheduler, it's built entirely in JavaScript. In the examples section you'll find lots of demos showing its different features.

http://www.ext-scheduler.com/examples.html

Disclaimer: I'm the author of it.